Написание TG бота с подключением базы данных
Столкнулся с необходимостью в написании TG бота, с подключением к нему базы данных. База представляет собой большое кол-во текстовых документов (более 200 гб). Ранее для работы с массой документов использовался "Архивариус 3000". Вывод результатов сделать похожим на результаты поиска в глазе бога. Сама база должна находиться на личном ПК. Ранее имелся опыт в написании простых ботов. Хотелось бы подсказки в каком направлении думать, или небольшого мануала, по данной теме..

Начните делать и если возникнут проблемы обращайтесь сюда. Как мне кажется на текущий вопрос невозможно дать объективный ответ.
